# Cannot locate an inline css in product page

Tags: magento2, css

I have installed a theme and trying to edit it. On product page I have found some blank space and while troubleshooting I have found that it is an effect of an inline css but I am unable to locate where is that inline css placed.
[image]

Please guide me in this.

Comment: The way these values are, they must be result of some JS , not inline styles. Wouldn't be very easy, but if you know which component's HTML this is, you can try your luck with the JS which is responsible for generating that component.

Answer (score 0):

> It should be on your **Theme's Setting Panel > Customization Settings** 
>    from the **Admin configuration**

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! But can you be more specific on the path that you gave above.

Comment: Log in to your Admin > Stores > Configuration > Theme's Setting Panel(This is the name of your theme) > Customization Settings (should be under your theme configuration tab)

Comment: Did not find solution of my query using your solution.

Comment: what theme are you using ?

Comment: I am using http://magicspellthemes.com/naturel/ theme for magento2.

Comment: what is the link of your website? I will check it maybe I can help you faster